# How can I make this git alias with quotes work?

Tags: git, alias

I want to make a git diff alias that only shows the changed lines (coloured).

```
[alias]
    mdiff = diff --color | grep --color=never $'^\e\[3[12]m'
```

This doesn't work, as apparently pipes cannot be used in git aliases, but [this answer shows a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19525426/140872):

```
[alias]
    mdiff = ! git diff --color | grep --color=never $'^\e\[3[12]m'
```

However, this does not work either and I still get this error: `fatal: bad config line 17 in file /home/me/.config/git/config`

A comment under that answer suggests that the problem is due to the quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A git alias without `!` is run by Git itself. If the alias contains a `|` character, that's just a `|` character. No shell is involved, so `|` doesn't mean a pipe.

A git alias starting with `!` is run by a shell. Git runs what follows the `!` in a shell (after doing some quote parsing), and passes the arguments at the end. Your second attempt is not valid because Git parses the backslashes, you need to double them, and double the backslash in front of `[` since the shell must see `\\[` in order for grep to see `\[`:

```
mdiff = ! git diff --color | grep --color=never $'\\e\\\\[3[12]m'
```

But this is not right because `git mdiff foo` is equivalent to running the shell command

```
git diff --color | grep --color=never $'\\e\\\\[3[12]m' foo
```

You need to arrange to pass the arguments to git. You can do that by defining a function and then executing it. You need to take care because `;` needs to be quoted. This works on the Git side:

```
mdiff = ! "f () { git diff --color \"$@\" | grep --color=never $'\\e\\\\[3[12]m'; }; f"
```

This only works if `/bin/sh` is bash, though, not if it's dash. Dash doesn't support the `$'…'` escape syntax. If `/bin/sh` is dash, you need to produce the escape character with `printf`.

```
mdiff = ! "f () { git diff --color \"$@\" | grep --color=never $(printf '\\033\\\\[3[12]'); }; f"
```

If all you want to do is remove the context (but keep file names and position indicators), that's built in: `git diff -U0`.

Comment: Thanks. The bash version doesn't seem to work (using bash), but the dash version is fine.

Comment: @paradroid I can't test easily because my `/bin/sh` is dash, but checking again I think it should be `$'\\e\\\\[3[12]m'`. Git sees 4 backslashes and puts 2 in the shell script. The shell sees two backslashes inside `$'…'` and passes one to grep. With just 2 backslashes, grep sees `␛[3[12]m`.

Comment: Awesome answer! Git aliases also allows \ to break lines to improve readability.